# How to change toggle state to original state if API call fails

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am building an application in which admins can deactivate/activate any employee. Basically when my page loads each employees' active state is bound into `mat-table` fetched from an API response. If an admin deactivates/activates any employee via another API call and that call errors out for some reason, I want the toggle to be switched to the previous state.

Example:
I fetch employee data from the database for `emp1` in `mat-table` with the following fields:
`id`, `fname`, `mname`, `lname`, `role`, `activestate` (true/false).
Now if I toggle `activestate` from true to false or visa-versa I make an HTTP call to the API respectively. If that API call fails for any reason, the user should see the original state of the `activestate` variable.

Here is the function I call when users change toggle state.

```
      /** Update employee is activated state*/
  updateEmployeeActiveState(e: any, empoyee: Employee, row) {
    console.log(row);
    var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    if (e.checked) {
      this.backendService.putEmployeeState(user.clientId, empoyee.employeeId, 1).subscribe(response => {

        this._snackBar.open(response.toString(), '', {
          duration: 3000,
          verticalPosition: 'bottom'
        });
      }, (error) => {

        this._snackBar.open("error -->"+error, '', {
          duration: 3000
        });
       this.dataSource.data[row].user.activeState = 0;
        
        
      });
    } else {
      this.backendService.putEmployeeState(user.clientId, empoyee.employeeId, 0).subscribe(response => {

        this._snackBar.open(response.toString(), '', {
          duration: 3000,
          verticalPosition: 'bottom'
        });
      }, (error)=> {

        this._snackBar.open("error -->"+error, '', {
          duration: 3000
        });
        this.dataSource.data[row].user.activeState = 1;
      });
    }
  }
```

Template code:

```
<!-- Is Activated Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="activeState">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Is Activated </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let rowNo = index;" data-title="User Name:"><mat-slide-toggle *ngIf="element.user?.userName" [checked]="element.user.activeState == 1" (change)="updateEmployeeActiveState($event, element, rowNo)" [(ngModel)]="element.user.activeState"></mat-slide-toggle></td>
  </ng-container>
```

Please ignore `row.user.activeState` as I was trying to reassign employee state but it didn't work.

Comment: Please also include the template code related to this snippet.

Comment: I wrote some new code in which if i get error i change user active state but a new problem now i am facing which is if i shutdown my server and toggle i get an error saying Typescripy:activestate=null cannot access

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

Your code is totally working with only one issue

Consider the below two line

```typescript
this.dataSource.data[row].user.activeState = 0;
...
this.dataSource.data[row].user.activeState = 1;
```

These lines do not trigger change detection. Consider adding a way to trigger change detection like using the spread operator **(...)**

```typescript
  // Update employee is activated state
  updateEmployeeActiveState(e: any, empoyee: Employee, row) {
     const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
     const activeState = e.checked ? 0 : 1
     this.backendService
       .putEmployeeState(user.clientId, empoyee.employeeId, activeState)
       .subscribe({
          next:() => {
             this._snackBar.open(response.toString(), '', {
               duration: 3000,
               verticalPosition: 'bottom'
              });
          },
          error: () => {
            this._snackBar.open("error -->"+error, '', {
              duration: 3000
           });
            // Change Back to initial state
            this.dataSource.data[row].user.activeState = !activeState;
            
            // Trigger change detection
            this.dataSource = [...this.dataSource]
          }
       })
  }
```